# Mongoose returns empty while the same query in mongodb shell works fine

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I know maybe this question has been asked quite many times here, I've went through several solutions people came with to similar questions but none of them seemed to help in my case.

I have two collections called `users` and `posts` and models for them look like this:

**users**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose').set('debug', true);
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var usersSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true}
});

var User = mongoose.model('user', usersSchema, 'users');

module.exports = User;
```

**posts**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose').set('debug', true);
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var postsSchema = new Schema({
    content: String,
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users',
        required: true
    }
});

var Post = mongoose.model('post', postsSchema, 'posts');

module.exports = Post;
```

I'm trying to get the posts of a user using this code:

```
var Post = require('../models/posts');

...

router.get('/posts/user/:userId', function (req, res, next) {
    Post.find({user: req.params.userId}, function (err, posts) {
        Post.populate(posts, {path: 'user'}, function(err, posts) {
            res.send(posts);
        });
    });
});
```

Mongoose debug mode reports that the following query is executed during the request:

```
posts.find({ user: ObjectId("592e65765ba8a1f70c1eb0bd") }, { fields: {} })
```

which works perfectly fine in mongodb shell (I'm using Mongoclient) but with Mongoose this query returns an empty array.

The query I run in mongodb shell:

```
db.posts.find({ user: "592e65765ba8a1f70c1eb0bd" })
```

The results I get:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("592e66b48f60c03c1ee06445"), "content" : "Test post 3", "user" : "592e65765ba8a1f70c1eb0bd" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("592e66b98f60c03c1ee06446"), "content" : "Test post 4", "user" : "592e65765ba8a1f70c1eb0bd" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("592e66bb8f60c03c1ee06447"), "content" : "Test post 5", "user" : "592e65765ba8a1f70c1eb0bd" }
```

I'm at the very beginning on learning Node.JS and MongoDB, so maybe I've missed something.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's because your actual data contains strings and not `ObjectId` values. See the difference between `_id` and `user` in the documents you provide? Your mongoose Schema is expecting `ObjectId`, and you probably should update the data so that the `user` property has `ObjectId` values. Simply search here for *"update all items  in collection"* or something similar.

Comment: Yes, probably you are right. I'll try to change the value type from string to ObjectId and see what happens. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As Neil Lunn suggested, I checked the user field type and it was indeed of type String instead of ObjectId so there was a mismatch of types between the data stored in collection and the field type from the query.

I used this code to convert the user field type from String to ObjectId in my collection:

```
db.getCollection('posts').find().forEach(function (post) {
        db.getCollection('posts').remove({ _id : post._id});
        tempUserId = new ObjectId(post.user);
        post.user = tempUserId;
        db.getCollection('posts').save(post);
    }
);
```

Now everything works as expected.